# Intellij, type hierarchy dialog, how to use keyboard to open file?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Enter doesn't work!

If you use the type hierarchy dialog in intellij it will list the classes as "Show members" feature in navigation pane normally does, which in turn results in that you cannot use the keyboard to open the file.

At least not with enter.

Do you really have to use the mouse to go there and click?

How can you open the file in Type Hierarchy using the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut is `Ctrl + Enter`.
Use `Esc` to get the focus back to the editor.

You can also press `F4` to both open the file and jump to the source code.

Those shortcuts can be adjusted at `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Keymap > Main menu > View > Show source` (first method) or `Jump to Source` (second method)-

Comment: I have overriden that CTRL + Enter key, might be why. What is the name of the current assignment? Does it exist?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can also use `F4` to both show the file and jump (= `Jump to source`)

Comment: Btw, it would so much nicer if you didn't had to hit ESC afterward you open it, very annoying. You open it, navigate hit enter, ( hide the dialog if not docked and pinned ). Now you always have to hit ESC and that's a hard one to reach.

Comment: More annoying is that all classes are not expanded by the default so that's a few extra keystrokes. Only for like 2 levels. I have this dialog on the left so there is hardly "too little" space to list all the files uncollapsed by the default or at least as an option.

Comment: See my update. Use `F4` only, it has the same effect as `Ctrl + Enter` followed by `Esc`. It's also possible to hide the panel automatically. Click on the little settings wheel on your panel and uncheck `pinned mode`. Now it will be hidden if it loses focus.

Comment: nice! I've now overriden this so that CTRL + ENTER does the same as jump to source! A+ for you :)